# How to solve the problem of connection failure after EC2 instance Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

My Ubuntu instance is 18.04. When I ran "sudo do-release-upgrade" to upgrade to Ubuntu20.04, it was normal. Other services were also normal. When I upgraded from Ubuntu20.04 to Ubuntu22.04 again, I used winscp and Putty cannot connect to the instance

This is the AWS console instance system log [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mInitial cloud-iniâ¦ob (metadata service crawler)[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mCloud-config availability[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mNetwork is Online[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSystem Initialization[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mACPI Events Check[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mresolvconf-pull-resolved.path[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt download activities[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily apt upgrade and clean activities[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily dpkg database backup timer[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mPeriodic ext4 Onliâ¦ata Check for All Filesystems[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDiscard unused blocks once a week[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mRefresh fwupd metadata regularly[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily rotation of log files[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily man-db regeneration[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mMessage of the Day[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mUpdate the plocate database daily[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDaily Cleanup of Temporary Directories[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDownload data for â¦ailed at package install time[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mCheck to see whethâ¦w version of Ubuntu available[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPath Units[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mTimer Units[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mACPID Listen Socket[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mcloud-init hotplug hook socket[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mD-Bus System Message Bus Socket[0m. Starting [0;1;39mDocker Socket for the API[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mOpen-iSCSI iscsid Socket[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSocket unix for snap application lxd.daemon[0m. Starting [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mUUID daemon activation socket[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPreparation for Remote File Systems[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mRemote File Systems[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mAvailability of block devices[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mDocker Socket for the API[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Listening on [0;1;39mSocket activation for snappy daemon[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mSocket Units[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mBasic System[0m. Starting [0;1;39mAccounts Service[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mAmazon CloudWatch Agent[0m. Starting [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m... Starting [0;1;39mDeferred execution scheduler[0m... Starting [0;1;39mLSB: Daemon for AWSLogs agent.[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mClamAV virus database updater[0m. Starting [0;1;39mcontainerd container runtime[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mRegular background program processing daemon[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mD-Bus System Message Bus[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mSave initial kernel messages after boot[0m. Starting [0;1;39mRemove Stale Onliâ¦t4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m... Starting [0;1;39mRecord successful boot for GRUB[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mirqbalance daemon[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mFUSE filesystem for LXC[0m. Starting [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m... Starting [0;1;39mAuthorization Manager[0m... Starting [0;1;39mPostfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mQualys cloud agent daemon[0m. Starting [0;1;39mresolvconf-pull-resolved.service[0m... Starting [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m... Starting [0;1;39mLSB: OpenLDAP staâ¦ Directory Access Protocol)[0m... Starting [0;1;39mService for snap application lxd.activate[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mPreparation for Logins[0m. Starting [0;1;39mSnap Daemon[0m... Starting [0;1;39mOpenBSD Secure Shell server[0m... Starting [0;1;39mUser Login Management[0m... Starting [0;1;39mDisk Manager[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDeferred execution scheduler[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mSystem Logging Service[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: automatic crash report generation[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRecord successful boot for GRUB[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: Daemon for AWSLogs agent.[0m. Starting [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mGRUB failed boot detection[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mAuthorization Manager[0m. Starting [0;1;39mModem Manager[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mOpenBSD Secure Shell server[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mRemove Stale Onliâ¦ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mUser Login Management[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mUnattended Upgrades Shutdown[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mLSB: OpenLDAP stanâ¦ht Directory Access Protocol)[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mDisk Manager[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mAccounts Service[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mModem Manager[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mresolvconf-pull-resolved.service[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mcontainerd container runtime[0m. Starting [0;1;39mDocker Application Container Engine[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mPostfix Mail Transport Agent (instance -)[0m. Starting [0;1;39mPostfix Mail Transport Agent[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mPostfix Mail Transport Agent[0m. [ [0;31m[0;1;31m[0m[0;31m* [0m] (2 of 3) A start job is running forâ¦ Container Engine (10s / no limit) M [K[[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mSnap Daemon[0m. [K Starting [0;1;39mWait until snapd is fully seeded[0m... Starting [0;1;39mTime & Date Service[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mTime & Date Service[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mWait until snapd is fully seeded[0m. Starting [0;1;39mApply the settings specified in cloud-config[0m... [ 16.893996] cloud-init[2179]: Cloud-init v. 23.3.1-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 running 'modules:config' at Thu, 19 Oct 2023 06:37:29 +0000. Up 16.84 seconds. [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mApply the settings specified in cloud-config[0m. Starting [0;1;39mPermit User Sessions[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mPermit User Sessions[0m. Starting [0;1;39mHold until boot process finishes up[0m... Starting [0;1;39mTerminate Plymouth Boot Screen[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mHold until boot process finishes up[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mSerial Getty on ttyS0[0m. Starting [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m... [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mSet console scheme[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Created slice [0;1;39mSlice /system/getty[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mGetty on tty1[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Reached target [0;1;39mLogin Prompts[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Finished [0;1;39mTerminate Plymouth Boot Screen[0m. [[0;32m OK [0m] Started [0;1;39mlibcontainer contaâ¦b859fc96d2ea413d79883d306aab5[0m. [ 18.835068] systemd[1]: Failed to create symlink /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls: Operation not permitted

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS ip-172-31-1-19 ttyS0

ip-172-31-1-19 login: [ 18.939311] cloud-init[2892]: Cloud-init v. 23.3.1-0ubuntu122.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 19 Oct 2023 06:37:31 +0000. Up 18.89 seconds. [ 19.011435] cloud-init[2892]: Cloud-init v. 23.3.1-0ubuntu122.04.1 finished at Thu, 19 Oct 2023 06:37:31 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local. Up 19.00 seconds